# SQL Server Collation Setting

Tags: sql-server, string-comparison, collation, accent-insensitive

In the SQL server, the default collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`, previously, I used to specify the collation explicitly at the end of each query to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI` to ignore the accents when comparing strings.

Now, I wanted to implement a generic solution, so that, I changed the database collation to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI` but the queries are still not working unless I specify the collation explicitly!
I searched a bit for this issue and I knew that the columns that were created previously using the old collation, have to be updated as well to the new collation or have to be dropped and recreated again!

### Is there any idea to handle this issue without updating all columns one by one?

---

Here is a sample of the queries that I have
With specifying the collation:

```
select * from Members where FirstName like '%cafe%' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
```

Without specifying the collation:

```
select * from Members where FirstName like '%cafe%'
```

Comment: If your column is in a different collation then when the comparison occurs then that column's collation will be used. If your columns are in the wrong collation then changing their collation is the correct solution, however, that isn't as simple task as just changing them, as some dependant objects will need to be `DROP`ed and re`CREATE`d.

Comment: I just want the simplest way to ignore the accents when comparing the strings, that's it!
If I couldn't find any simple way, I'll have to update all columns' collations

Comment: Changing the column's collation is what you want to do, as syntax using `COLLATE` isn't SARGable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a script to change the collation of all columns in all tables using the following code:

```sql
DECLARE @fromCollation sysname = 'collation_name_here', @toCollation sysname = 'collation_name_here';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT
  CONCAT(
    'ALTER TABLE ',
    QUOTENAME(s.name),
    '.',
    QUOTENAME(t.name),
    ' ALTER COLUMN ',
    QUOTENAME(c.name),
    ' ',
    typ.name,
    '(',
    c.max_length,
    ') COLLATE ',
    @toCollation,
    IIF(c.is_nullable = 1, ' NULL', ' NOT NULL')
  )
FROM sys.tables t
JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
JOIN sys.types typ ON typ.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
WHERE c.collation_name = @fromCollation
  AND typ.name IN ('varchar', 'nvarchar', 'char', 'nchar');
```

If you have any non-clustered indexes, or any schema-bound functions or views, you would need to drop and re-create them.

Comment: That's usually far from enough to just change the column collations because indexes, inline functions etc might depend on the columns being changes.

Comment: For functions only if they have `WITH SCHEMABINDING` otherwise it works fine to just change it.

Comment: @Charlieface, unfortunately, this solution doesn't fit as we have many indexes related to the columns we need to update!

Comment: Probably easeist to just use a tool to script all the indexes and constraints as drop/create